# using one ViewController for all button xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, uiviewcontroller

I am building an app with lot buttons on Front. now I don't want to create ViewController for each button because I have 30 buttons and I have to create 30 view-controller . all I want is to when I click on the first button. 
open 
wahstatus.com
on the second button
wahstatus.com/ws/punjabi-funny-status

something like this as I have implemented in the android app

```
if (id == R.id.button1) {

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://m.punjabidharti.com/pd/punjabi/");
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();

        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    } else if (id == R.id.button2) {

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://m.punjabidharti.com/pd/punjabi/funny-punjabi/");
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();

        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Is it possible in Xcode? Thanks

Comment: You can create custom view and use it in every view controller

Comment: Subclass UIViewController.

Comment: @ElTomato it has nothing to do with subclassing UIViewController

Comment: Treat ViewControllers as separate screens. 30 buttons doesn't mean 30 view controllers. If you want to have them in 1 screen that it is 1 view controller and 30 UIButton instances.

In case you need to differentiate buttons by ids like you showed above use tags. Assign them in Storyboard and then check tag property in source code.

Comment: whats the code ?

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing with your buttons is opening URLs, you don't even need to create your own view controller at all. I suggest you use `SFSafariViewController`, which is very easy to present.

First add the Safari Services framework to your project and add this to the top of your vc with all the buttons:

```
import SafariServices
```

Then you can navigate to a safari view controller with a small method like this:

```
func presentSafariVC(for url: URL) {
    let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: urlString)
    present(safariVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: how can i switch url one to another ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Do you mean a different url on each button press?

Comment: on button 2 another url will load

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you misunderstood the meaning of [UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller):

> A view controller manages a set of views that make up a portion of your app’s user interface

You don't create a UIViewController for every button. If your buttons are complicated and complex you can create a a [NIB](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html) file with a corresponding .m and .h files (or .Swift file) that subclass UIView for example. Using this solution you can then add your NIB file (which is a subclass of UIView) to any UIViewController you want - or to any UIView.

If your buttons are simple and what you need is a single IBAction method that handles all the taps (using the [responder chain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/understanding_event_handling_responders_and_the_responder_chain)) it is also possible. Just open your Storyboard and connect all the buttons (using ctrl + drag) to that single IBAction method.

Comment: There's no more .m and .h files with Swift :)

Comment: @nyg The code syntax looks like Objective-C - He write the type before defining the instance name also, the if statement has parentheses. updated the answer..

Comment: Indeed it's not Swift, but I think it's Java code as he says "something like this as I have implemented in the android app".